# soapui xml tag value update using groovy script

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I have below web service request. I am trying to update a property using groovy script.

**Webservice:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:ChangeLengthUnit>
         <web:LengthValue>${=(int)(Math.random()*9999)}</web:LengthValue>
         <web:fromLengthUnit>Inches</web:fromLengthUnit>
         <web:toLengthUnit>Centimeters</web:toLengthUnit>
      </web:ChangeLengthUnit>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Groovy script:**

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )  

// get XmlHolder for request message def 
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "ChangeLengthUnit#RawRequest" ) 

// change password using XPath 
holder["//*:LengthValue"] = "1234"  

// write updated request back to teststep 
holder.updateProperty()
context.requestContent = holder.xml
```

I am unable to update Lengthvalue tag using above script. I an getting below error

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA error at line: 4
```

Comment: You are already using dynamic value. Why do you want to update again?

Comment: @Rao, I have some special characters to be passed in the request xml. Above example is similar to my issue. I am not using random value in my actual project.

Comment: Ok, with what value you want to update the request? A static value each time or dynamic one? Are you using free version or pro?

Comment: I am using free version. I will be updating request xml with a dyamic value from previous service response. Normal property expansion failing as the tag has special characters. Hence I am using groovy script property transfer.

Comment: Can you show the previous response and which value needs to be extracted and set it in the above request?

Comment: @Rao, Response xml has this tag `<ns0:name>Sherly &amp; ' ^ " * 123456 </ns0:name>`

Comment: @Rao, I found out the issue. I shouldnt be updating rawrequest, it should be request only. Thanks you rao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do that in a simpler way

Lets say your xml request was

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
  <web:ChangeLengthUnit>
     <web:LengthValue>1234</web:LengthValue>
     <web:fromLengthUnit>Inches</web:fromLengthUnit>
     <web:toLengthUnit>Centimeters</web:toLengthUnit>
     <web:name>Sherly &amp; ' ^ " * 123456 </web:name>
  </web:ChangeLengthUnit>
```

you can get the value of name with the below script

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )  

// get XmlHolder for request message def 
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "First Step#Request" ) 

def x= holder.getNodeValue("//*:name")

 log.info x

 testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Prop",x)
```

So what we have done in above code is got the value "Sherly & ' ^ " * 123456 " and created a custom property and added value in it.

Now you could easily use that value in the next request

```
<web:LengthValue>${#TestCase#Prop}</web:LengthValue>
```